# Como invocar a função no HTML

Tags: javascript

Galera, eu estou iniciando no JS e gostaria de saber como eu faço para exibir os resultados da função product() no html, pois no console.log ela funciona corretamente (console.log(product(1, 2, 3)))
Alguém consegue dar um help? Obrigado

```js
function product(x, y, z) {

  var arg1 = document.getElementById('arg-1').value
  var arg2 = document.getElementById('arg-2').value
  var arg3 = document.getElementById('arg-3').value
  if (x !== undefined && y === undefined && z === undefined) {
    return x;

  } else if (x !== undefined && y !== undefined && z === undefined) {
    return x + y;
  } else if (x !== undefined && y !== undefined && z !== undefined) {
    return (x + y) / z;
  } else if (x === undefined && y === undefined && z === undefined) {
    return false;
  } else {
    return null;
  }
}

console.log(product(1, 2, 3))
```

```html
<input type="number" id="arg-1">
<input type="number" id="arg-2">
<input type="number" id="arg-2">
<button onclick="product()">Submit</button>
<p id="saida"></p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opa thiago, para você exibir isso no html, você precisa dar um [innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) na div que você quer exibir o resultado.

```js
function product(x, y, z) {
    if (x !== undefined && y === undefined && z === undefined) {
        return x;

    } else if (x !== undefined && y !== undefined && z === undefined) {
        return x + y;
    } else if (x !== undefined && y !== undefined && z !== undefined) {
        return (x + y) / z;
    } else if (x === undefined && y === undefined && z === undefined) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
var saida = document.getElementById('saida') // pega a div

var valor = product(1, 2, 3) // armazena o valor
saida.innerHTML = valor //exibe o valor
```

```html
<p id="saida"></p>
```

Notei também no seu código que você está declarando a variável `arg3` de forma errada, referenciou o id `arg-2`

Se você quer, e claramente quer, passar os valores dos inputs invés de martelar eles, você vai ter que fazer um tratamento também na hora de ler esses valores, um [Number](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_number.asp) ou [parseFloat](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) resolvem sua vida.

Espero ter ajudado!!

Comment: Opa, cara ajudou muito era isso mesmo, valeu!